# Android 11 and above pose compatibility issues when attempting to use the native camera app within Unity to capture photos

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera, android-11

fellow developers! I'm currently working on an Android app using Unity 2021.3.14f1. In order to capture photo and manage it on my application, I've been utilizing the following code snippet to launch the native camera app.

```
AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.MediaStore");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE"));

AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            unityPlayerActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

With the required permissions granted, this code block effectively opens the camera app and allows for capturing photos on both Android 10 and Android 11+. However, on Android 11+, there is an issue where the taken photo is not being saved to the device's memory. This is important because I'm catching photo with active directory (I'm open to alternative methods).

It appears that Android has made changes to its security management, resulting in the inability to obtain permission to save photos to the external public directory, even when using the native camera app.

Here is the function that I use to retrieve the directory for searching photos that have been taken:

```
private string GetPhotoPath()
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass environment = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Environment"))
        {
            using (AndroidJavaObject directoryDcim = environment.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getExternalStoragePublicDirectory", "DCIM"))
            {
                using (AndroidJavaObject directoryCamera = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", directoryDcim, "Camera"))
                {
                    return directoryCamera.Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And getting permissions using code below on android manifest. It seems to overkill but I tried all one by one to find solution.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
```

Also tried to take permissions on runtime. It didn't solve the issue.

I tried to add extra output to camera intent to save photo on application internal datapath. Here my code snippet:

```
// Create an intent to start the camera activity
AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.provider.MediaStore");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE"));

// Create the output file path for the captured image
string outputFilePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/myNewPhoto.jpg";
AndroidJavaObject outputFile = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", outputFilePath);

// Get the file path as a Uri
AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject outputUri = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", outputFile);

// Add the output Uri as extra (EXTRA_OUTPUT) to the intent
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_OUTPUT"), outputUri);

// Start the camera activity
AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject unityPlayerActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
unityPlayerActivity.Call("startActivity", intentObject);
```

This way i got the Error Unity AndroidJavaException: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/myNewPhoto.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri(). Here is details of the error : [FileUriExposedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException)

Used chatGPT to solve problem and it said i should use fileprovider on android 11 to access storage.
I added a fileprovider named file_paths.xml to Plugins/Android/xml/ location on my project. Here file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path
        name="camera"
        path="Camera/" />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="/" />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="/"/>
</paths>
```

I tried many variations of this xml.
Added this to androidmanifest

```
                <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.mycompany.myapp.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@Plugins/Android/xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This way i got the error on building the app :

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Projects\Unity\myapp\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\unityLibrary\build\intermediates\library_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:105:13-107:70: AAPT: error: '@Plugins/Android/xml/file_paths' is incompatible with attribute resource (attr) reference.
```

To solve this i start using custom gradle and gradle.properties.
Added  :

`android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`
to gradle.properties

And added :

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.0.1"}
```

but this changes effected nothing.

I also tried to used GetPhotoPath function instead of application.persistantdatapath but issued same error.

Can't see anything to try at this moment. Can you give me any idea?

Comment: `in the inability to obtain permission to save photos to the external public directory` No. Not at all. Your app can freely write picture files to public DCIM and Pictures directories.